# Power bi growth current year to all other years

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two event year filters one being the main year and the other being the compare years. The main year is a single select and then compare years is a multi select. then end user gets to select the event year they want to compare against the other years. what I am trying to do is get a growth rate from the main year to each individual compare years.

What I have right now
Dax from measures:

Total Registration Main Year =
CALCULATE(
SUM(FactActivity[ActivityCount]),
FILTER(
FactActivity,
FactActivity[ActivityType] = "Registration"
),
FILTER(
DataSense_V2_Event,
DataSense_V2_Event[ShowYear] IN (ALLSELECTED('Year First Selection'[ShowYear]))
)
)

Total Registration Compare Year =
CALCULATE(
SUM(FactActivity[ActivityCount]),
FILTER(
FactActivity,
FactActivity[ActivityType] = "Registration"
),
FILTER(
DataSense_V2_Event,
DataSense_V2_Event[ShowYear] IN (ALLSELECTED('Year Second Selection'[ShowYear]))
)
)

Growth Rate
Return (_CompareYear - _MainYear) /_CompareYear

Data
| Show Year | Total | Main Year   | Compare Years | Growth Rate |
| --------  | ----- | ----------- | ------------- | ----------- |
| 2023      | 2447  |  2447       |               | Infinity    |
| 2022      | 4845  |             | 4845          | 1           |
| 2019      | 3981  |             | 3981          | 1           |

this is what i am looking for

| Show Year | Total | Growth Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 2447 |  |
| 2022 | 4845 | - 50% |
| 2019 | 3981 | - 38% |